# Migrate from local Git repository to TFS source control project with all history

Tags: git, tfs, migration

I have a local Git repository and I needed to migrate all the code and all history to TFS source control project.
Anyone has a solution to share?

*PS: I already know how to make the migration from local Git to TFS Git based Team Project.*

Answer (score 3):

You can migrate all history of main branch from local repo to a new TFVC team project with following steps:

1. Create an empty TFVC team project
2. Go to your local Repo folder, and use `git-tf checkin --deep` command to checkin the local repo to a TFVC team project. By default, the checkin command will create a single TFS changeset for the aggregate of all changes made on the current branch in Git since the last checkin to TFS. When used with the **--deep** option, a TFS changeset will be created for each Git commit on the current branch since the last checkin to TFS.

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this does not preserve the change set commit dates.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't do that!!! (that's not the way the history is going... Microsoft invest less and less in TFVC and a lot more on gut, their internal teams switching massively on git. You are doing a step in the past and should at least a last time convince your management to not do that not clever move. Git is here to stay and surely not TFVC so the sooner you adopt it, the better it is.)
2. You can't migrate all the history, just the history of the main branch.
3. Have a look at git-tf

Edit: my feeling was good... TFVC is no more a source control of the future. Microsoft itself is moving away and standardise around Git for ALL its projects!

Comment: Why shouldn't someone migrate from Git to TFVC if they don't want to or cannot use Git?

Comment: Downvoted--while you suggest a valid answer (git-tf; thank you), please don't presume you know what's best for OP, by saying "Don't do that!!!"

Comment: @iokevins I hope that other will be able to better read between the lines than you and that doesn't worth a downvote. It was more a funny advice and if I provide a good clue to the answer, that's because, like you said, that every one is free to do what it wants (even if he is heading to bigger problems)... And by downvoting, you tell others that my answer is worthless even it contains the solution :-(

Comment: Hi @Philippe, it's not personal. If you prefer, please edit your answer to indicate you meant the first point humorously, and I'll remove the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: @Philippe In my case it's a requirement by our corporate client to use TFVC so how does your advice help me?

Comment: This is wrong and terrible advice. TFS is not going anywhere and git is such a pita why keep using such a piece of garbage.

Comment: @fsteveb All the software industry is standardizing our git, even Microsoft (and TFVC don't evolve anymore). Who do you think is wrong, you or everyone? Git is a lot more flexible and permit to do a lot more things but this power needs indeed some effort to learn...